# Understanding atheistic idealism

Tags: metaphysics, idealism, atheism

Berkeley holds the world together by saying it is God's idea. But how can we explain the shared world of experience in an atheistic idealism like Schopenhauer's?

Comment: Can you give any starter ideas as to why not, how such idealism does not?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't even one that is asked by a philosophy of atheistic idealism. Do application focused physicists go around asking "Why does gravity exist?" The world is. There doesn't need to be an explanation for that, the physical world is the physical world.

Comment: Actually, some physicists do exactly that.

Comment: Replaced "physicists" with "application focused physicists." You are right that some do. I was thinking of someone who wants to model dynamic fluids, not a theorist. Thank you for pointing that out.